# Check if date valid using moment and format 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS+ss:ss' does not work

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to check if a string `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSS+ss:ss`
But I always get `false`.

For example:

```
const value = '2022-02-16T22:23:53.000+00:00'
moment(value, DATE_FORMAT, true).isValid();
```

Please advise, am I using the wrong format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date format should have been - `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ`